# Server.MapPath não acha a pasta no meu projeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando salvar um arquivo em uma pasta no meu projeto (No caso na pasta Arquivos):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas da o seguinte erro quando entra na action:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Cadastrar(ArquivoPasta oArquivo,HttpPostedFileBase arquivo)
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Arquivos"+arquivo.FileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            byte[] bytesLogotipo = new byte[arquivo.ContentLength];
            arquivo.InputStream.Read(bytesLogotipo, 0, arquivo.ContentLength);
            stream.Write(bytesLogotipo, 0, arquivo.ContentLength);
            ViewBag.Mensagem = "Arquivo Salvo com sucesso nessa merda!";
            return View();
        }
```

Eu criei a pasta no lugar errado ou o código está errado?

Answer (score 2):

Falta uma barra...

```
Server.MapPath("Arquivos\"+arquivo.FileName)
```